# Troubles with Flask and CSS

Tags: python, css, flask

I have following structure of my project:

```
templates
    index.html
static
    style.css
testFlask.py
```

I try to add `style.css` (with `url_for`, or manually), but url `localhost:5000/static/style.css` says `Page not found`

Here code from testFlask.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, g, redirect, url_for,flash
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Code from index.html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

Finally, I recreated my style.css and now everythings is fine.
Thanks for attention!

Comment: We'll need to see the relevant portion of code in your template

Comment: Yes, please post your code from `testFlask.py`.

Comment: @user8289 okay thank you - and now can we see how you're trying to access your stylesheet inside `index.html` please?

Comment: Ok, I did it) Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tested your code/template snippets here with flask 0.8 (the version from the Debian package) and i cannot reproduce the problem -> the style.css is found.
Maybe permissions on static directory are to restrictiv? If i remove read access to the static directory for the user that runs testFlask.py the 404 appears.

best wishes,
Matthias